# Have you ever found this phenomenon in sgmaker studio lab?

Tags: jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1pxi.png)

There is no runtime available right now. Please change the compute type or try again later.

I dont know why?Because of my pause?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why sometimes a runtime might not be available is because of GPU availability (or the lack thereof, to be precise). With the gloabl GPU shortage, GPUs are high in demand and sometimes there is just not a GPU available. If you try again at a later time, it should (hopefully) work again.

Comment: thx,I have known the reason is the shortage of GPU.Maybe I should use it on Workdays.

Comment: The last 10 days I never found a GPU runtime available.